# How can I put consecutive numbers in an active range of cells using VBA?

Tags: vba, numbers

I have a selected series of 400 cells in one common and want to number them. However, I want this to be dynamic so if I select a bigger range it will number them.  Basically how do I number the active cells.  I tried doing it using a macro but because of the way my data is structured there is nothing in the row to start and consequently I couldn't get an xldown function to work.  Thanks in advance I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you have a `Selection` then you can work directly with that.

Answer (score 0):

This will fill either a single-column or single-row contiguous selection (i.e. a single area):

```
Sub Tester()

    With Selection
        If .Columns.Count = 1 Then
            .Value = .Parent.Evaluate("Row(1:" & .Rows.Count & ")")
        ElseIf .Rows.Count = 1 Then
            .Value = Application.Transpose( _
                  .Parent.Evaluate("Row(1:" & .Columns.Count & ")"))
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```